# Existence of an inverse in Fundamental group and continuity of homotopy

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $X$ be a topological space and let's denote $\pi_1(X,1)$ for it's Fundamental Group of loops at base 1. I'm going through the proof that Fundamental Group is indeed a group and I have a question about the proof of the inverse axiom from Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology".

Let's denote $I = [0,1]$ and fix a path $f:I \rightarrow X$ (Hatcher shows this on more generally on paths instead of loops). Let's define $\overline{f}:I \rightarrow X$ as
$$\overline{f}(s) := f(1-s).$$
We want to show that we have the following equality for homotopy classes: $[f][\overline{f}]=[e_0]$, where $e_0$ indicates the constant path at $f(0)$. The idea is the following: we define $H(t,s): I \times I \rightarrow X$ by
$$H(t,s) = \begin{cases}
f(2s), &0\leq s \leq \frac{1}{2} - \frac{t}{2}\\
f(1-t), &\frac{1}{2}-\frac{t}{2} < s \leq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{t}{2}\\
f(2-2s), &\frac{1}{2}+\frac{t}{2}<s \leq 1.
\end{cases}$$
This $H(t,s)$ is the key since this will be a homotopy between $f \cdot \overline{f}$ (where $\cdot$ indicated product of paths) and $e_0$, since $H(0,s) = f \cdot \overline{f}(s)$ and $H(1,s) = e_0$, giving us our result.

My question is about the continuity of this function, to actually show that it's a homotopy. It's easy to see from the definition that $H(t,s)$ is continuous for each $t$ if we fix $s$, and for each $s$ if we fix $t$, but if I understand correctly the whole point is for $H(t,s)$ to be continous with respect to $(t,s)$ "at the same time". Honestly, I don't really feel what is the idea behind showing that $H(t,s)$ is continuous with respect to $(t,s)$, since the position of $s$ depends on $t$ in the definition, so I'm not exactly sure what kind of limits I should study (or perhaps this question is just silly and trivial?). I would really appreciate some insight here.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use the so called pasting lemma. In order to do that, change the strict inequalities to weak inequalities. For example the set in the middle will be $\{(t,s): \frac{1-t}{2}\leq s\leq \frac{1+t}{2}\}$, which is a closed subset of $I\times I$. The restriction to each of these $3$ sets will give you a continuous functions, so by the pasting lemma $H$ itself is continuous.

Comment: By the way, if you care about formal proofs then Hatcher's book is not a good option. I honestly don't remember even one proof in this book which actually convinced me. Just nothing rigorous there, not an exact science book by any means. I learned about the fundamental group from Munkres and that was great. For example, Munkres proves the statement you asked about without even defining the actual homotopy, just a theoretical proof which doesn't leave any doubts.